# How to insert a slice into Redis database using Redix.v3

Tags: go, redis

Getting an error while inserting a slice into Redis database using redix.v3. What's redis command to insert a slice? SET or HMSET?

My code:

```
type Domain struct {
    ID         string `json:"ID,omitempty"`
    ParentID   string `json:"parentID,omitempty"`
    ParentType string `json:"parentType,omitempty"`
    Owner      string `json:"owner,omitempty"`
    PATEnabled string `json:"PATEnabled,omitempty"`
    Name       string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

for _, domain := range domains {

    if err := client.Do(radix.FlatCmd(nil, "HMSET", domain.ID, domain)); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)

    }
```

Error message:

> could not marshal value of type Domain

Comment: what is the struct domain?

Comment: type Domain struct {
 ID                              string        `json:"ID,omitempty"`
 ParentID                        string        `json:"parentID,omitempty"`
 ParentType                      string        `json:"parentType,omitempty"`
 Owner                           string        `json:"owner,omitempty"`
 PATEnabled                      string        `json:"PATEnabled,omitempty"`
 Name                            string        `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

Comment: Hi Benjamin, struct domain is presented above. thanks

Comment: Redis doesn't know how to convert your custom type `Domain` into a value that can be written to redis. Try implementing interface `encoding.BinaryMarshaller` on `Domain`. https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#BinaryMarshaler